# How composite objects are released when the NSMutableArray that contains those objects are released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
@implementation TestClass

- (id) init
{
    string = [[NSString alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (void) release
{
    [string release];
}

@end



@implementation MainScreen

- (void) addItems
{
    [myMutableArray addObject:[[[TestClass alloc] init] autorelease]];
}

- (void) release
{
    [myMutableArray release];
}
```

My Question is when we release the myMutableArray, will it call the release method of TestClass or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not how Cocoa memory management works. When you add the object to the array, the array expresses that it owns the object by sending the `-retain` message. The array keeps this ownership until it itself disappears (i.e. is deallocated), then it no longer needs the object and sends it `-release` to relinquish ownership. The array does not need to retain or release the objects every time it is retained or released.

To summarise: objects retain other objects when they need to take ownership of them, and release them when they no longer need that ownership.

This points to your memory management of the `string` ivar being incorrect. You correctly take ownership of a zero-length string in `-init` (where I'm using "correctly" in a very loose sense), but then every time your object is released it releases the string. Consider:

```
TestClass *obj = [[TestClass alloc] init];
[obj retain];
[obj release];
[obj release];
```

the above is likely to crash (and if it doesn't, you're very unlucky). You should release the string in `-dealloc`, when your object finally doesn't need it any longer. If you change the object referred to by the ivar, you also have to change the ownership.

Comment: Hi Thankz for pointing out that special case. I never thought of that. But my doubt is when we add the TestClass objects into the array it type becomes id, i believe. So when we dealloc the array, is the release method of NSObject called thereby leaking the string, or will it call the release method of TestClass.?

Comment: First: that's not a special case, it's actually the case you've documented in your question. It doesn't magically change type. The point of object-oriented programming is that objects specify their own behaviour, so if you send an object a message you get that object's behaviour and no other.

Comment: Objective-C (on iOS) doesn't have a fragile base class problem.

Answer (score 3):

Never ever override `-release`! What you want to override is `-dealloc`! And in there you have to call `[super dealloc]`

Please read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf

And to your question, if your array gets deallocated, every object in the array is sent a `release` message.

Comment: "if you release an array, every object in the array is sent a release message." – This is not necessarily true. See my comment to Tudorizer's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be overwriting the - (void) dealloc method, not the -(void) release one; and always call [super dealloc] at the end. 
Yes, releasing an NSMutableArray releases the individual objects too.

Comment: "Yes, releasing an NSMutableArray releases the individual objects too." is not true. _Deallocating_ the array will release the individual objects. _Releasing_ the array will only lead to deallocation if no other object has retained it.

Answer (score 1):

just as

```
[myMutableArray addObject:[[[TestClass alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

will increment retainCount to the TestClass instance

so will release decrement the retainCount for all objects in the array

note that `dealloc` is the method to implement in your custom class, it is called when your object is released.

Comment: Untrue. See the comments on every other answer that has made the same statement.